# How to gragle compile Custom Tabs when sdk is 25?

Tags: android

I take a reference on official website https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

They gradle like this :`compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.3.0'`

My project had used a lots of compile gradle that the sdk is 25 , i don't want to change it.

Is anyone to compile gragdle Custom Tabs when sdk is 25 ? Thanks in advance.

Here is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.my.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'//i don't want to change it.
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.3.0'//is this with verson 25 ?
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

Comment: Try to compile custom tabs with 25, sure the updates came to it.

Comment: thanks , i try compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.0.0' , it works .

I have a question that is there any document about it ?  I just try it by guess.

Comment: If nothing new to custom tabs it should have the same documentation

Comment: i see , then i just guess it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
 dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.1.0' //25.2.0 has been published 
}
```

**Advantages**

- Customizing the UI and interaction with the custom tabs.
- Making the page load faster, and keeping the application alive.

Read **[Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs)**